# Script component generating multiple output files

Tags: ssis

I have one SSIS package deployed in INT and Dev environments respectively. Inside that package, I have one Data flow task that uses one OLEDB source and Script component (used as a destination) respectively.

OLEDB source component uses one stored procedure to generate the data.

Now the issue is:

If I execute the package in INT then I'm getting multiple output files in the shared path and if I execute the same package in Dev then I'm getting only one output file.

I have compared both the versions of stored procedure in INT and Dev and they are same!!

Not sure what exactly is the issue. Please advice

Answer (score 2):

Logically, if the same code is operating in two different environments and producing different results, then something else must be different. In your case, I am going to bet it's an underlying data issue. You have made an assumption based on data in DEV that is not valid in INT.

By choosing a script component for your destination, you are in complete control of how your output is generated so either update your code to account for the scenario in INT that results in multiple files or get your data in INT cleaned up to not cause the situation in the .NET code.

If you need more a detailed answer, we'll need a more detailed question. Please update your question and add your

- .net code
- stored proc signature (col1 int, col2 varchar(30), etc)
- possibly some sample data